# Removing all elements from the list with the matching id using python

Tags: python

I have a python list that has user id , team id and activity id like the below
actually these are records extracted from mysql database using cursor and converted to a list

```
((18459L, 1152L, 9494L), (9097L, 580L, 6243L), (14641L, 580L, 9394L))
```

(18459L, 1152L, 9494L) is one element suppose i want to remove all elements from the list that has a userid value 18459L how to perform such deletion operation any ideas to suggest on the same.

Comment: Do you want to delete elements from the existing list (actually a tuple, that can not be modifed), or create a new, filtered list of the other elements?

Comment: That is not a list, but a tuple...

Comment: delete from existing list I'm running a for loop on that and the list has about 650,000 records the execution is very slow if i find one such occurrence have to remove all the  elements that occurs with that user id and continue iterating the loop

Comment: But is this a list or tuple? you can use filter.

Comment: it was a tuple from mysql and it was converted to a list

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple list comprehension for this

```
A = ((18459L, 1152L, 9494L), (9097L, 580L, 6243L), (14641L, 580L, 9394L))
print tuple([i for i in A if i[0] != 18459L])
```

Output:

```
((9097L, 580L, 6243L), (14641L, 580L, 9394L))
```

If you have multiple users to remove then use the below snippet:

```
toRemove = [18459L, 18451L, 18452L]
A = ((18459L, 1152L, 9494L), (9097L, 580L, 6243L), (14641L, 580L, 9394L), (18451L, 1152L, 9494L), (18452L, 1152L, 9494L))
print tuple([i for i in A if i[0] not in toRemove])
```

Comment: well this works but if im running the for loop on same tuple i want to remove these users from that so that no of iterations will reduce any way to do that?

Comment: You can use the "in" instead of comparing. Updated solution. is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `filter()` to do this:

```
>>> lst = (('18459L', '1152L', '9494L'), ('9097L', '580L', '6243L'), ('14641L', '580L', '9394L'))
>>> tuple(filter(lambda x: x[0] != '18459L', lst))
(('9097L', '580L', '6243L'), ('14641L', '580L', '9394L'))
```

Comment: well have an issue in this for example if i have a for loop like for i in tuple if i filter the user value from the tuple the main tuple where it is currently looping is not modified it still loops through all elements when i remove i want the loop to be modified so that iterations is reduced